# Forward network traffic from one computer to another using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, iptables

I have two computers on the same lan

```
Comp A: 192.1681.151.15
Comp B: 192.1681.151.19
```

The setup is like this

```
Internet <---->  Computer B
      ^-------->  Computer A
```

Both computers have a single network card.

When I open Wireshark, for all traffic browsed on comp A, I would like Wireshark to capture traffic of comp A and destination address as the one to the server it is connecting too.

I have tried to understand iptables and other related questions, but somehow I still configure this wrongly.

I use the following iptable rules on comp B

```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:443 
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:80 
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

However when I browse traffic on comp B, I do not see any traffic on wireshark (running on comp A). Can someone please guide me how to configure this properly ?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you are trying to do? Do you want to capture all of Computer A's traffic on Computer B? Or are you trying to capture all the traffic on the network on Computer B?

Comment: I want to capture all of computer A's traffic on computer B. You can think of it as Comp B is a proxy/gateway to comp A

Comment: Did you update the route on Computer B when you made the `iptables` change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are really two questions, and I'm not sure that they are related.

1) If the computers are connected by ethernet LAN via a switch, and not WLAN, all traffic on the LAN is in principle visible to all devices connected to it. No need to do masquerading/forwarding or use any iptable rules. So just fire up Wireshark on any computer, say, computer B, and you should see the traffic from computer A to the router.

If that doesn't work, ping computer B from computer A. Then ping the router from computer A. If you don't see packets from the first ping, something with the Wireshark setup doesn't work correctly. If you only see packets from the first ping, and not from the second ping, the interface drops packets not intended for that computer for some reason, or something is filtering out packets, so check iptables on computer B etc.

**Edit**: What also can happen is that your router is not acting as a switch. I tested a bit and found I actually had one router where all 4 LAN ports appear as distinct devices, and are bridged (including WLAN) using a Linux kernel bridge. This kind of bridge keeps track of MAC addresses it has seen, and only forwards to the port where it has seen the destination MAC address. In this case, packets from the two computers can't be seen on the other machine.

Solutions: (a) Find some other ethernet switch and connect everything to it, or (b) use the gateway method.

2) If you want to use computer B as the gateway for computer A (which is not necessary to just obvserve traffic on ethernet LAN, but may be necessary e.g. for WLAN), you need to configure computer A to use computer B as the gateway. Very likely your "internet" in your setup is a home router, which acts as a DHCP server, assigns IP addresses to computer A and computer B, and tells them to use the router as a gateway. So use `route` or `ip route` to set the correct route on computer A. Make sure there are no other routes.

The following script works for me to set up forwarding (though maybe it's not optimal):

```
#!/bin/bash

# forward traffic on the same $IF for one particular $ADDR, acting as gateway

modprobe nf_conntrack
modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
modprobe nf_nat
modprobe iptable_nat  

IF="eth0"
ADDR="192.168.178.25"

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF -o $IF -d $ADDR -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF -o $IF -s $ADDR -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $ADDR -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the ip route rule. I added the following after a flushing all the current rules in the iptables. `ip route add default via <IP addr of comp B> ` . I can now see traffic that I browse on comp A in wireshark (installed in comp B). However, when I block all packets by adding rules in comp B like `iptables -P INPUT DROP
` (and the same rule for OUTPUT and FORWARD table)  I can still browse traffic on comp A. Shouldn't the packets be blocked on comp A as well.

Comment: 1) All iptable rules on B only affect what B does with those packets. No matter what rules you choose, when A sends packets to B, these packets will show up on the interface, and you'll see them in wireshark. Also, I don't really understand *why* you'd want to block them... 2) Do `ip route` and `ip -6 route` on A, and make sure the *only* route is the default route to B. If there are other routes present, A can still e.g. contact the router directly to browse etc. If you do this and doesn't set up forwarding on A correctly, B won't be able to connect to the internet at all.

Comment: I just deleted all the routing tables on A using the ip route del command. The routing table for Computer B is like http://pastebin.com/7jmwuWx8 and the routing table for Comp A is here http://pastebin.com/rTXzy58R   On comp B, I ran this command echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward . All iptables are flushed, however there is still no internet connectivity. I do not  understand why this does not work

Comment: No internet connectivity on computer A. I ran the script that was added to the post on comp B to take care of the forwarding rules on B. Computer B has internet connectivity.

Comment: You have changed `ADDR` to the actual address of computer A, and `IF` to the actual LAN interface of computer B?